# oodle.com API - Use it with PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

I am working on a web-application using PHP/Ajax , It include an RSS aggregator of blog posts , I want to add a new functionality that gives us the ability to post into oodle or vast.
I tried to integrate the oodle.com API with PHP but I didn't find enough support .
http://www.oodle.com/info/feed

Did any one try to work with this API ? , I am looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you may use the form http://www.oodle.com/submitfeed to register a feed. oodles reads items from this feed automatically.

Comment: I am looking to make this feature like Tweet bottoms that allows as to retweet and share link to Twitter . I wonder to know how can we make this feature available using the API .